Static resource does not show correct color in .NET MAUI
I have this label inside a layout in the XAML file:
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label 
        Text="¡ Bienvenido a tu enrolamiento !" FontFamily="RobotoRegular" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"
        TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Tertiary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}"
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</VerticalStackLayout>

On the other hand, I have this in Colors.xaml file:
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Color x:Key="Primary">#512BD4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Secondary">#DFD8F7</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Tertiary">#2B0B98</Color>
    <Color x:Key="White">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Black">Black</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray100">#E1E1E1</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray200">#C8C8C8</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray300">#ACACAC</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray400">#919191</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray500">#6E6E6E</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray600">#404040</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray900">#212121</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray950">#141414</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryBrush" Color="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TertiaryBrush" Color="{StaticResource Tertiary}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WhiteBrush" Color="{StaticResource White}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="{StaticResource Black}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Gray100Brush" Color="{StaticResource Gray100}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Gray200Brush" Color="{StaticResource Gray200}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Gray300Brush" Color="{StaticResource Gray300}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Gray400Brush" Color="{StaticResource Gray400}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Gray500Brush" Color="{StaticResource Gray500}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Gray600Brush" Color="{StaticResource Gray600}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Gray900Brush" Color="{StaticResource Gray900}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Gray950Brush" Color="{StaticResource Gray950}"/>

    <Color x:Key="Yellow100Accent">#F7B548</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Yellow200Accent">#FFD590</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Yellow300Accent">#FFE5B9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Cyan100Accent">#28C2D1</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Cyan200Accent">#7BDDEF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Cyan300Accent">#C3F2F4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Blue100Accent">#3E8EED</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Blue200Accent">#72ACF1</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Blue300Accent">#A7CBF6</Color>

</ResourceDictionary>

when I run the app in both iOS and Android, the text is shown with a yellow color:

What is it wrong here?
Just in case, tis is the Styles.xaml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="ActivityIndicator">
        <Setter Property="Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="IndicatorView">
        <Setter Property="IndicatorColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedIndicatorColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray100}}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
        <Setter Property="StrokeShape" Value="Rectangle"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="BoxView">
        <Setter Property="Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Primary}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="14,10"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Editor">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Frame">
        <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ImageButton">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="SeparatorColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
        <Setter Property="RefreshControlColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Picker">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="TitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                            <Setter Property="TitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="ProgressColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="ProgressColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="RefreshView">
        <Setter Property="RefreshColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="SearchBar">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray500}" />
        <Setter Property="CancelButtonColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray500}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="SearchHandler">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray500}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Shadow">
        <Setter Property="Radius" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
        <Setter Property="Brush" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Offset" Value="10,10" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="MinimumTrackColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="MaximumTrackColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
        <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="MinimumTrackColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="MaximumTrackColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="SwipeItem">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Black}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Switch">
        <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{StaticResource White}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="On">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Secondary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray400}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TimePicker">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Page" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Black}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
        <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="{OnPlatform WinUI={StaticResource Primary}, Default={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.NavBarHasShadow" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Black}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="IconColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TabbedPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="UnselectedTabColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="SelectedTabColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>


So you're saying it looks ok in Windows but not in Android nor iOS? Have you checked for a colors.xml in Platforms/Android/Resources/values and/or Platforms/iOS folders?

@StephenQuan there is a colors.xml file in Android folder which defines colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent. In iOS folder there is no colors.xml file. Since that text appears yellow in both Android and iOS, I think there is a common definition that is wrong. By the way, I didn't say it looks OK in Windows. Visual Studio shows that color OK while developing and editing the XAML file.

I started a new .NET MAUI project and put your code in it, but, the problem is not reproducible:

If you scrutinize the difference between your screenshot and mine, you'll note that numerous differences indicate that the color and various font settings are not being applied.
There are several troubleshooting steps you can do:

Start with a new .NET MAUI application (as I've done) and progressively copy your code into until it breaks, then, you have a minimal reproducible problem and we can look at what happens
Alternatively, take your current application and start progressively removing code until it starts working

